# cakephp instead of user_id how do I get for instance username in the view

Tags: mysql, cakephp, controller

I have 3 tables: users, comments and videos.

In my videos view.ctp I can't get the username displayed, only the user_id.

I can't figure it out, can someone point me in the right direction?

**User model:**

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false
        ),
}
```

**Video model:**

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
            'dependent' => false
        ),
}
```

**Comment model:**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'Video' => array(
            'className' => 'Video',
            'foreignKey' => 'video_id'
        )
    );
```

}

**Videos view.ctp**

```
<?php if (!empty($video['Comment'])): ?>
      <?php foreach ($video['Comment'] as $comment): ?>
         <p><?php echo $comment['comment_created']; ?></p>
         <p><?php echo $comment['User']['user_username']; ?></p>
         <p><?php echo $comment['user_id']; ?></p>
         <p><?php echo $comment['comment_body']; ?></p>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**VideosController**

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->loadModel('Comment');
    if (!$this->Video->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid video'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Video.' . $this->Video->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('video', $this->Video->find('first', $options));

    $current_user = $this->Auth->user('user_id');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Comment->create();
        /*save the current's user id in database*/
        $this->Comment->set('user_id', $current_user);
        /*save the current's video id in database*/
        $this->Comment->set('video_id', $id);
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You\'re comment has been placed.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view/' . $id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You\'re comment could not be placed. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('users', 'videos'));
}
```

Comment: Why are there 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '','order' => '', like empty things

Comment: is removing empty things resolved your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Can we discuss here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94517/room-for-pradeep-singh-and-gilko

Comment: I updated my question and have put my whole controller code in it. When putting <?php debug($video); ?> in the view or in the controller it gives me either 'null' or nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

In the controller:

```
$comments = $this->Video->Comment->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Comment.video_id' => $id)));
```

In the view:

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <p><?php echo $comment['User']['user_username']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $comment['Comment']['comment_created']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $comment['Comment']['comment_body']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```